# Convert backbone.js into react backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, backbone.js

I am transferring my rails project view into react. The rails project uses the backbone.js. Do I also have to write all the code again in react backbone. Or there is some shortcut to avoid this whole writing of backbone code again. I am using react on rails gem.

Comment: you need to rewrite your views in react anyway. You can reuse the models/collections/controllers though. https://www.engineyard.com/blog/integrating-react-with-backbone

Comment: @Praveen, I have been told not to use react backbone. I am stuck how to start. Basically from where to start.